# Understanding JavaScript performance variance

Tags: javascript, performance

http://jsfiddle.net/6L2pJ/

```
var test = function () {
    var i,
        a,
        startTime;

    startTime = new Date().getTime();

    for (i = 0; i < 3000000000; i = i + 1) {
        a = i % 5;   
    }
    console.log(a); //prevent dead code eliminiation
    return new Date().getTime() - startTime;
};

var results = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i = i + 1) {
    results.push(test());
}

for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i = i + 1) {
    console.log('Time needed: ' + results[i] + 'ms');
}
```

Results in:

First execution:

```
Time needed: 13654ms 
Time needed: 32192ms 
Time needed: 33167ms 
Time needed: 33587ms 
Time needed: 33630ms
```

Second execution:

```
Time needed: 14004ms 
Time needed: 32965ms 
Time needed: 33705ms 
Time needed: 33923ms 
Time needed: 33727ms
```

Third execution:

```
Time needed: 13124ms 
Time needed: 30706ms 
Time needed: 31555ms
Time needed: 32275ms
Time needed: 32752ms
```

What is the reason for the jump from first to second row?

My setup:

- Ubuntu 13.10
- Google Chrome 36.0.1985.125 (Mozilla Firefox 30.0 giving same kind of results)

EDIT:

I modified the code leaving it semantically the same but inlining everything. Interestingly it does not only speed up the execution significantly but it also removes the phenomena that I described above to a great extent. A slight jump is still noticable though.

Modified code:

http://jsfiddle.net/cay69/

Results:

First execution:

```
Time needed: 13786ms 
Time needed: 14402ms 
Time needed: 14261ms 
Time needed: 14355ms 
Time needed: 14444ms
```

Second execution:

```
Time needed: 13778ms 
Time needed: 14293ms 
Time needed: 14236ms
Time needed: 14459ms 
Time needed: 14728ms
```

Third execution:

```
Time needed: 13639ms 
Time needed: 14375ms 
Time needed: 13824ms 
Time needed: 14125ms 
Time needed: 14081ms
```

Comment: A video on your facebook wall started autoplaying

Comment: Yeah, this is probably just ordinary variation depending on what other processes are running....if you ran the test again you'd probably get a different result.

Comment: A program on your computer started sending data back to NSA headquarter/

Comment: No! I ran it again and it gave me similar results!

Comment: Why are you not taking this seriously? I will post further results here. I left the PC idle during the computation...

Comment: Btw test it yourself. You should see the same results. I did it over and over again. Use the fiddle I posted.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm glad that this takes 3 minutes to even attempt to help you debug.

Comment: Can't reproduce in Mozilla.

Comment: See edits for setup. The thing is that I did not encounter this effect when using a rather low number of iterations. If you think it makes no difference I'm sure you can handle it to adjust the one single number that is necessary to reduce the computation time ;)

Comment: @user2820379 - One interesting thing I see is that if you preset all variables to `0`, the differences are gone.

Comment: You mean initialize everything like so: `var x = 0`?

Comment: @user2820379 - See my answer, though I don't really have an explanation for that.

Comment: have you tried it without the `console.log` line? (Perhaps replace `console.log` with some other task.) In my experience Chrome sometimes struggles when you log too much.

Comment: Derek posted this as an answer a moment ago and we came to the conclusion that it speeds up the execution significantly but most probably only because the interpreter ignores the calculation since `a` is not used anymore. Also 10 log statements don't make for seconds of execution overhead AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit testing, I think I have pin-pointed what may be causing the difference. It must have something to do with type *I think*.

```
 var i,
     a = 0,
     startTime;
```

`var a = 0` gives me a uniformed result with an overall faster performance, on the other hand `var a = "0"` gives me the same result as yours: the first one is somewhat faster.

I have no clue why this happens.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot reproduce your results. Using `a = 0` doesn't result in any difference for me.

Comment: @user2820379 - I must say there are many environmental variables that might vary the result. It does have an effect on my machine (Windows).

Comment: Okay that is interesting. Don't get me wrong, I'm obviously not suspecting you to lie about something like this. I'm just pointing out that on my environment this does not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Google Chrome is breaking up your script execution into chunks, and giving processing time to other processes.  Its not noticeable until your execution hits around 600ms per function call.  I tested with a smaller subset of data (300000000 if I remember correctly.)

Comment: Where are you taking the 600ms from?

Comment: Oops, forgot to add that I used a smaller subset of data.

Answer (score 0):

The following is only a pseudo-answer, which I hope may become updated by the community.  Originally, it was going to be a comment, but it became too lengthy, too quickly and thus needed to be posted as an answer.

---

### Interesting/Findings

In [running a few tests](http://jsfiddle.net/6L2pJ/1/), I couldn't find any correlation to `console.log` being used.  Testing in OSX Safari, I found that the problem existed with and without printing to the console.

What I did notice was a pattern.  There was an inflection point as I approached 2147483648 (2^31) from your initial starting value.  This most likely depends on the user's environment, but I found an inflection point around 2147485000 (try numbers above and below; 2147430000..2147490000).  Somewhere around this number is where the timings became more uniform.

I was really hoping it would be 2^31 [exactly], since that number is also significant in computer terms; it is the upper bound of a `long` integer.  However, my tests resulted to a number that was slightly more than that (for reasons unknown at this point).  Other than making sure the swap file wasn't being used, I didn't do any other memory analysis.

---

EDIT from asker:

On my setup it actually is exactly 2^31 where the jump occurs. I tested it by playing around with with the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/8w24v/

---

*This information may support Derek's initialization observation.*

***This is just a thought and might be a stretch:***
The LLVM or something else may be  performing some up-front optimizations.  Perhaps the loop variable starts out as an `int` and then after a pass or two the optimizer notices the variable becomes a `long`.  In trying to optimize, it tries to set it as a long up front, only in this case it's not an optimization that saves time, since working with a regular integer performs better than the conversion cost from int to long.

*I wouldn't be surprised if the answer was somewhere in the [ECMAScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.5) documentation* :)

Comment: Can you report how long one iteration takes you (i.e. one of the five values)?/ I'm asking because I suspect that if `console.log` does not make any difference in execution time for you then maybe the browser does not perform dead code elimination.

Comment: I can confirm your findings: Before some value around 2147483648 execution times are uniform and also remarkably shorter.

Comment: @user2820379 and @vol7ron: Calling a [slightly modified version](http://jsfiddle.net/w23Xv/) of the function (taking the number of iterations as argument) multiple times first with e.g. 3 times `25000000` then with two times with `2500000000` and then again 3 times `25000000`  shows a significant slowdown for all of them after `2500000000`. But that would essentially mean that the JIT splits up the function into multiple parts.

Comment: @user2820379 (you should make a name), I did not say the `console.log` did not make any difference in execution time.  That is not what is being evaluated here. I said it did not make a difference in the variance between iterations of the loop.  To be clearer, when you ran the test 5 times, you noticed it was quicker on the first, and the later 4 all took some seconds longer (but were roughly the same as eachother).  `console.log` had no difference if it was present, or not; there was a difference (for me) between loop iterations.

Comment: What was more interesting is that as the number I used approached 2^31, I found that more of the tests fell closer to the first iteration's duration.  So as it approached 2^31, the first 2 (of 5) iterations ran much quicker.  Choosing an even closer number to 2^31 made the first 4 (of the 5) iterations run quicker. --- I also found that changing the number of iterations (from 5 to 3) caused that inflection number to go up (away from 2^31).

Comment: I'll also add that as stated before, this was in WebKit-based browsers; my testing in Firefox (Windows and OSX) did not experience this anomaly.

Comment: In Firefox for Windows, I experience this. Furthermore, counting down from 2^31 has the same behavior. I modified the jsfiddle from above so that Start Test runs the function twice, and anytime after runs it a single time. If you click to start the test later, the behavior goes back to normal. But if you click it as soon as the last test run finishes, it lags again. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/8w24v/6/